# How to convert a CSV file into an HTML listing

Tags: html, csv, data-conversion

Most of the Q&A I found online on this topic were about converting a `CSV` file into an `HTML` table, which is **not** what I am trying to achieve here.

I have a `CSV` table with 70+ entries and the following columns:

- Name
- Year
- Duration
- Location
- Price
- Link
- Pitch
- Details

And I would like to convert it into `HTML` code to upload to our website, such as:

```
<h3>Name</h3>

<ul>
  <li>When: `Year`</li>
  <li>How long: `Duration`</li>
  <li>Where: `Location`</li>
  <li>How much: `Price`</li>
  <li>What: `Pitch`. `Description` <a href="`link`">Learn More</a>.
 </ul>
```

**[EDIT]**: the idea would be to use the CSV file like a database and iterate on each row, generating HTML based on the available values.

What is the best way to write a script that would accomplish the above?

Comment: Which language(s) are you using? This is fairly trivial with JS or PHP.

Comment: What does the CSV use as a delimiter? Is it guaranteed all fields are filled, is there any blanks, if so how are they represented?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what your looking for:

[CVS to HTML List Converter](http://cvs-to-html.jacks.tech)

I just made it. If it need changed or modified let me know or your free to take the html document and change it as you need.